# How to wrap header caption in Janus GridEx

Tags: c#, windows, janus, gridex

I'm using Janus controls in my Windows Application (NOT WPF) with .NET 2.0. In all of the grids in my application, I want to wrap the caption of column header. I tried many codes and searched for it for a long time. But no used. Would anyone help me to wrap the caption of the grids in Janus?
Something like this:

"This is a long header"

becomes:

"This is a

long header"

PS: As you know, the control name is GridEx.

With thanks.
(Down-voters! please excuse my simple question and my poor English language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ColumnSet` in `GridEx` properties and add all columns in it.

Set `ColumnSetHeaderLines = 2` (if you need you can increase according to your header size).

Also set the `GridEx` root table property:

```
CellLayoutMode = UseColumnSet
```

Comment: I didn't find GridEx properties !,where is it?